problem in python with customtkinter and sqlite3
I want to make it so that when the button is clicked, the values from the name, surname, password fields are taken and inserted into the sqlite3 table, but it turns out that when the script starts, empty values are inserted into the sqlite3 table, and when the button is clicked, nothing works
главный скрипт:
import customtkinter
import tkinter
from module import User


password = 0
surname = 0
name = 0
app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry('300x250')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
database = User('DBs.db')

#---------ФРЕЙМ РЕГИСТРАЦИИ--------
def userdata():
    global password
    password = pass_entry.get()
    global name
    name = name_entry.get()
    global surname
    surname = surname_entry.get()
    database.new_user(name, surname, password)
    database.connection.close

register_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app,
                                        width=290,
                                        height=240,
                                        corner_radius=10,
                                        )

name_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=register_frame,
                                    width=220,
                                    height=40,
                                    placeholder_text='name',
                                    placeholder_text_color='grey'
                                    )
                                    
name_entry.place(anchor = 'n', relx = 0.5, rely = 0.10)
surname_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=register_frame,
                                    width=220,
                                    height=40,
                                    placeholder_text='surname',
                                    placeholder_text_color='grey')

                                    
surname_entry.place(anchor = 'n', relx = 0.5, rely = 0.30)
pass_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=register_frame,
                                    width=220,
                                    height=40,
                                    placeholder_text='password',
                                    placeholder_text_color='grey')
                    
pass_entry.place(anchor = 'n', relx = 0.5, rely = 0.50)

register_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=register_frame,
                                          width=220,
                                          height=40,
                                          text='Регистрация',
                                          command=userdata(),
                                          corner_radius=10)
register_button.place(anchor='n', relx = 0.5, rely = 0.70)


#-------ЛОГИН ФРЕЙМ--------
login_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app,
                                     width=290,
                                     height=240,
                                     corner_radius=10)


name_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=login_frame,
                                    width=220,
                                    height=40,
                                    placeholder_text='name',
                                    placeholder_text_color='grey'
                                    )
                                    
name_entry.place(anchor = 'n', relx = 0.5, rely = 0.10)
surname_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=login_frame,
                                    width=220,
                                    height=40,
                                    placeholder_text='surname',
                                    placeholder_text_color='grey')

                                    
surname_entry.place(anchor = 'n', relx = 0.5, rely = 0.30)
pass_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=login_frame,
                                    width=220,
                                    height=40,
                                    placeholder_text='password',
                                    placeholder_text_color='grey')
                    
pass_entry.place(anchor = 'n', relx = 0.5, rely = 0.50)

#--------ЛОГИН ИЛИ РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ ФРЕЙМ-----------

reg_or_log_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app,
                                          width=290,
                                          height=240,
                                          corner_radius=10)
reg_or_log_frame.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

def registration():
    app.title('РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ')
    reg_or_log_frame.pack_forget()
    register_frame.pack(pady = 0, padx= 0, expand=True)
    
def login():
    app.title('АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ')
    reg_or_log_frame.pack_forget()
    login_frame.pack(padx = 0, pady = 0, expand = True)
reg_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=reg_or_log_frame,
                                     width=220,
                                     height=40,
                                     corner_radius=10,
                                     command=registration,
                                     text='registration'
                                    )
reg_button.place(anchor='center', rely = 0.5, relx=0.5)

reg_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=reg_or_log_frame,
                                     width=220,
                                     height=40,
                                     corner_radius=10,
                                     command=login,
                                     text='login'
                                    )
reg_button.place(anchor='center', rely = 0.7, relx=0.5)


app.mainloop()


скрипт модуля module:
import sqlite3

class User:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/inkoa/Desktop/login_and_password/' + db_file, check_same_thread=False, autocommit=True)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdata(
                            "name" TEXT,
                            "surname" TEXT,
                            "password" TEXT
        )''')
    
    def new_user(self, name, surname, password):
        self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO userdata VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (name, surname, password,))


что мне сделать?
nothing helps...
idk what to do
